# JPA+Swing is there a way to use a single Connection?

Tags: swing, jpa

I'm in a process of rewriting a part of Oracle Forms code to Java Swing as a demo (just a showcase for Oracle people to see how it looks and feels). I'd rather use JPA than play directly with JDBC.

The problem is, (as with any Oracle Forms apllication, I guess) that each application user has a separate Oracle account/schema, and the program relies heavily on keeping track of stuff via Oracle session-tied package variables. When they decide whether they want a web app or a desktop one, they will probably have to make a hard decision and switch to a different model, but for now I have to play the cards I've been dealt.

So - is there a way to configure Hibernate (or any other) JPA so that it works with a single Connection object (and try to reconnect in case it's dropped)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you use EclipseLink you have a few options.  One is using Oracle proxy authentication, the other is to connect each EntityManager with a user id.

See,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Auditing